# All files locked

Tags: permissions, files

All of my files and folders have become locked!
I cant run anything from terminal requiring files because it says permission denied and I have to open all files from root if I want to do anything with them. Please help :O

Oh and my themes dont work so Im assuming its because they are locked too :/

Comment: Try `stat /home/<your_name>` and `stat /run/user/1000`, from the output of which you should notice something wrong.

Comment: Try `stat /home/<your_name>` and `stat /run/user/1000`, from the output of which you should notice something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have inadvertently changed the ownership of those files to some other system user (root, or some such)

I'd usually fix this by opening up a terminal window and doing something like:

```
cd /home/ccrama/
sudo chown -R ccrama *
```

Be careful - you don't want to do this anywhere outside your home directory, as that can mess things up.

If you don't know what these commands do, typing "man " at the command line will open up the documentation for that command- like:

```
man chown
```